# What is the connection between the Metal Heads and the Dark Makers?

Tags: jak-and-daxter

in *Jak 3* when Jak and Daxter find out that Errol is working with the Dark Makers (i believe it was in the Metal Head Tower) Jak says

> The Dark Makers don't play well with others. Just ask the Metal Heads

Now i've played the previous 2 games and i don't recall any hints at the Dark Makers or even any sort of connection between them and the Metal Heads.

So what is the connection between the Metal Heads and the Dark Makers Jak seems to be implying when he tells Errol that the Metal Heads know that the Dark Makers don't play well with others.

Answer (score 1):

It's never explicitly mentioned when the [Metal Heads](http://jakanddaxter.wikia.com/wiki/Metal_Heads) and [Dark Makers](http://jakanddaxter.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Makers) were in an alliance, only that at some point they were allies before the Dark Makers betrayed the Metal Heads.

However, we can speculate that an "enemy of my enemy" scenario took place, as both the Metal Heads and Dark Makers were warring with the Precursors. The most likely scenario is that the Dark Makers forged an alliance with the Metal Heads and used their armies to defeat the Precursors, before betraying them because, as Jak says, they "Don't play well with others".